# Is there a way to output multiple lists from a single list comprehension expression?

Tags: python

Something like

```
x, y = [expression for d in data]
```

Basically I'd like to obtain the equivalent of this:

```
x = []
y = []
for d in data:
    x.append(d[0])
    y.append(d[1])
```

where `data` is a nested list?

And what if data is a list of dictionaries?

```
x = []
y = []
for d in data:
    x.append(d['key1'])
    y.append(d['key2'])
```

And what if I want to apply a different function to each column where data is a list of dictionaries?

```
x = []
y = []
for d in data:
    x.append(func1(d['key1']))
    y.append(func2(d['key2']))
```

Comment: Can you provide how `data` looks like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
x, y = zip(*[d[:2] for d in data])
```

I think is what you want ... that will give you a list of x's and a list of y's

if each row in data only has d[0] and d[1] then you can just do

```
x1,x2,x3 = 1,2,3
y1,y2,y3 = 3,4,5
data = [(x1,y1),(x1,y2),(x3,y3)]
x,y = zip(*data)
```

if you have a dict

```
from operator import itemgetter
x,y,z = zip(*map(itemgetter('key1','key2','key3'),data))
```

if you wanted to apply a function you would need to do

```
x,y = zip(*[(function1(row['key']),function2(row['key2'])) for row in data])
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! What if data is a list of dictionaries instead?

Comment: Thanks! What if I want to apply a different function to data corresponding to different keys?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [53]: dta = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]

In [54]: dta
Out[54]: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

In [55]: zip(*dta)
Out[55]: [(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6)]

In [56]: x,y = zip(*dta)

In [57]: x
Out[57]: (1, 3, 5)

In [58]: y
Out[58]: (2, 4, 6)
```

Comment: Which REPL are you using? I see this "IN" and "OUT" a lot here.

Comment: Ipython is great because of its magic functions and its --notebook switch :P ... but it always kills my terminals stdout when I exit it, which forces me to close my terminal ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley I've never had it kill my stdout, but then again I never use the --notebook switch.

Comment: @JoranBeasley You should be able to CTRL-C or CTRL-\ in the terminal to kill the IPython kernel. The reason the kernel still runs after you close the browser is that sometimes you want to leave a notebook "up" longer, or you may just want to run a notebook in the background so that others can navigate to it via their browsers. It's not generally the case that you will want IPython to be killed just because the notebook tabs in a browser were closed. What if you closed them accidentally, for example? Do you want to re-execute every cell of the notebook?

Comment: naw im not talking about using the ipython --notbook switch... just my cmd.exe (Im on windows which likely is part of the problem) is always messed up even after I kill ipython  ... and I have to close my terminal